How do the "vials" in the Fallout series affect ghoul transformation into feral ghouls?
In the 2024 Fallout TV series (Season 1, Episode 4: "The Ghoul"), there’s a scene where Lucy (Ella Purnell) and The Ghoul (Walton Goggins) encounter Roger, a ghoul on the brink of becoming a feral ghoul (a zombie-like creature). Roger’s transformation is imminent because he’s run out of "vials." It’s also disclosed that The Ghoul is also dependent on these mysterious vials to stave off the same fate.

This caught my attention because, as a long-time fan of the Fallout franchise, I don’t recall this gameplay element from my playthroughs of Fallout 3, Fallout: New Vegas, and Fallout 4. My memory might be a bit rusty, but I don’t remember any gameplay mechanic where ghoul companions needed such vials to prevent turning feral. It’s possible that this is a detail that’s lore-only and is not reflected in the gameplay.
Does the concept of ghouls needing vials to stave off ferality have any basis in established Fallout lore? If so, what is the nature of these "vials" depicted in the TV series?

No, ghouls have never been mentioned as needing any drugs to stave becoming feral, and we don't know what these vials do in the TV series

We don't know what it is exactly, but watch further and you'll get more info about them.
